# How to create a new extension to save an Excel file? Similar to .xlsx is it possible to create new extension using C# eg: .newext

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

Is it possible to make a new Excel extension like .xlsx?  While saving the file, a new extension should appear in the help list.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, in the WinForm project

```
  var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
  dialog.AddExtension = true;
  dialog.Filter = "The custom(*.newext)|*.*";
  dialog.ShowDialog();
```